# Get variable from Angular custom directive in a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The question may sound a bit weird, and if so, please apologize my ignorance. I am very new with AngularJS and have to get a variable that is in a custom directive, from a Javascript function.

This is the directive (it reads a csv file and I want the headers of such file):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('csvReader', [function ($scope) {
// Function to convert to JSON
var convertToJSON = function (content) {

  // Declare our variables
  var lines = content.csv.split('\n');
  var headers = lines[0].split(content.separator);

      scope: {
          heads: headers;

      };   

  var columnCount = lines[0].split(content.separator).length,
      results = [];

  // For each row
  for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {

      // Declare an object
      var obj = {};

      // Get our current line
      var line = lines[i].split(new RegExp(content.separator + '(?![^"]*"(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)'));

      // For each header
      for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {

          // Populate our object
          obj[headers[j]] = line[j];
      }

      // Push our object to our result array
      results.push(obj);
  }

  // Return our array
  return results;
 };
```

The variable that I need to get is headers, and what I did was placing such value in the scope through scope.heads=headers, as reflected in the code.

In the html, I need to get whether the headers variable or the scope.header. For this purpose, I have a Javascript function that looks like this (in the html file):

```
<script>
function change() {
    var scope = angular.element($("#outer")).scope();//this is for a <div> to be updated every time the scope.heads variable changes
    scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.heads = angular.element('[csv-reader]').scope.heads; //this does not retrieve the data and is actually my problem.
    })
}
</script>
```

As I said, I am very new with Angular, but I know I can get variables from a controller this way:

```
function change() {
    var scope = angular.element($("#outer")).scope();
    scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.heads = angular.element('[ng-controller=fieldsController]').scope().heads; //this works perfectly, of course I have a controller called fieldsController and inside I have the variable scope.heads
    })
}
```

Is it possible to get the variable that I need from the custom directive into Javascript in the html part?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all: this is a bad idea, reconsider your architecture. Why are you not using a solution within the confines of angular? If you tell us more of the problem you're trying to solve, maybe we can help coming up with a better method to do it.

Second: `headers` is private to that directive's `convertToJSON` function, so you can't get a reference to it from the outside. To make it accessible, put it on the scope (since you already have a method to fetch variables from the scope).

Also, this part is probably not the syntax you're looking for - what is it supposed to do?:

```
scope: {
      heads: headers;
  };
```

What this currently does is defining a [labelled block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) with a label 'scope'. Were you trying to extend $scope with the `headers` property? Try something like this:

```
$scope.heads = headers;
```